# Can you input a directry into a program from the terminal when you run the program?

Tags: python

I have written a program that runs many different functions to analyse data collected from an infrasound array. The files are picked from a directory using glob. I want the user to be able to change the directory the files are taken from when the program is run from the terminal. Because of the eventual use of the program I don't want the user to be asked to input the directory, I just want them to be able to do as they start to run the program. Is there a way of doing this?
This is the code used to import files into the program, so it is n that needs to be changed by the user:

```
#Insert filenames into the script. 

n='/home/helen/2014/test_scripts/test1/'

os.chdir(n)

a = glob.glob("*B130*")
if not a:
    fname1='no file'
else:
    f1=a
    fname1 = ''.join(f1)
b = glob.glob("*B117*")
if not b:
    fname2='no file'
else:
    f2=b
    fname2 = ''.join(f2)
c = glob.glob("*B099*")
if not c:
    name3 ='no file'
else:
    f3=c
    fname3 = ''.join(f3)
d = glob.glob("*B104*")
if not d:
    fname4='no file'
else:
    f4=d
    fname4 = ''.join(f4)
```

I am new to python so might have done this in a bit of a long winded way but it has worked for me.

Comment: if you place some of your code . expected output will greatly help us to solve

Comment: I think you are looking for `argparse` which is built into the core library.

Answer (score -1):

With [os.getcwd()](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/os.html#os.getcwd) you can get the current working (starting) directory. Do you mean that?

Comment: The directory used needs to be changed by the user without them ever seeing the program. Would os.getcwd() enable that to happen? I have never used it so don't understand what it does, sorry.

Comment: I don't think it is a command line tool. Sorry I'm really new at all of this!

Comment: Ah thank you for your code ... you can fill `n` by `os.getcwd()` instead of the path to your directoy. Then, everytime the script will be started, the current working directory of the user will be used for `n`. But I don't understand than the line `os.chdir`? You want that the directory will be used the user stays in, right?